# Comparing timestamps between different machines

Tags: linux, timestamp, low-latency, performance

The environment I'm working in involves **multiple machines (Linux) on a LAN processing data in a chain**. I'd like to **timestamp** things in a way so I can see when it is **received/sent** by each node to later compare the timestamps for the whole chain. This is a low-latency system.

I would like to understand if it is **feasible to compare timestamps taken on different machines with resulution microseconds**. What kind of services does one usually use to synchronize the clocks and what resolution is possible to expect? What about clock drifts and other things?

E.g. N nodes and all need to have the clocks synchronized on the second/millisecond/microsecond, is that possible, what is required and what is the overhead?

And of course I'd like it to be as non-intrusive to the network and processing time as possible. ;-)

Am I completely looking at something impossible or can this be done?

Looking forward to reading your answers! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your machines are within a LAN you can probably achieve an accuracy of `200-500` microseconds using a local `NTP` server. This isn't particularly network or CPU intensive.

Comment: Yes, they're on a LAN and I've read that this could be set up. I'm just wondering what other possibilities there are around. Can it get better and what do people ususally do?

Comment: I've heard of people actually using cheap `GPS` devices that are remarkably accurate (for their price) - a few milliseconds accuracy.

Comment: @cnicutar: This is an awesome idea. GPS time is tamper-proof and does not depend on some ethernet cable's capacity or latency.

Comment: @cnicutar: sounds very interesting. But you say milliseconds...this would be worse than your own NTP server and setting it up to do very frequence syncs. Or did you mean microseconds? ;)

Comment: @murrekatt I did say milliseconds and meant it. `NTP` is probably the superior solution **in your lan**. But on the public internet.. without some solid `QoS` / leased line (think $$$) `NTP` doesn't always fare so well.

Comment: @cnicutar: do you have a reference where it states the time accuracy?

Comment: @murekatt I don't :-) I vaguely remember the scales from a lecture a long time ago.

Comment: Well, GPS time is used in international bank transfers, because of its reliability and accuracy. Depending on how many sattelites your receiver will read, accuracy can be somewhere in the tens to fifties of nanoseconds, if I remember well. Though some particular devices might only report back milliseconds... still having a _precise_ millisecond resolution is better than having an _unprecise_ microsecond resolution. Take Windows FILETIME for example, you have 100ns resolution, but only between 1ms (kernel) and 1h (filesystem) precision. They could as well truncate 6 digits, nobody would notice.

Comment: @Damon: thanks for the information. Very interesting. Would you have a reference to this or somewhere I can read more about what you're saying?

Comment: A quick google brought up this one, which claims 15ns: http://trl.trimble.com/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-183796/Resolution-T_DS.pdf